# Schedule sql query on create of new record

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to a schedule an sql query when a new record is added. At the moment I have a query that is scheduled to execute once a day at a certain time.

Thanks,

EDIT 1;
Thank you everyone for your comments. To test this here is my trigger below, is my syntax correct?
What im trying to do, is when a data is entered convert it to TitleCase.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TableInsert]
ON [Table] 
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @InputString varchar(4000) 
DECLARE @Index          INT
DECLARE @Char           CHAR(1)
DECLARE @PrevChar       CHAR(1)
DECLARE @OutputString   VARCHAR(255)

SET @OutputString = LOWER(@InputString)
SET @Index = 1

WHILE @Index <= LEN(@InputString)
BEGIN
SET @Char     = SUBSTRING(@InputString, @Index, 1)
SET @PrevChar = CASE WHEN @Index = 1 THEN ' '
                     ELSE SUBSTRING(@InputString, @Index - 1, 1)
                END

IF @PrevChar IN (' ', ';', ':', '!', '?', ',', '.', '_', '-', '/', '&', '''', '(')
BEGIN
    IF @PrevChar != '''' OR UPPER(@Char) != 'S'
        SET @OutputString = STUFF(@OutputString, @Index, 1, UPPER(@Char))
END

SET @Index = @Index + 1
END

RETURN @OutputString

END
```

EDIT 2:
 `@InputString` was used  when calling the function.

```
update dbo.mytable
set fieldName=[dbo].[InitCap](@InputString);
```

In my case `@InputString` was the fieldname that was being updated.

Comment: You can't schedule something that happens at random times. You can however use a trigger for this kind of thing. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx

Comment: Just be sure if you use triggers that you don't use scalar variables. A trigger in sql server fires once per operation, not once per row.

Comment: The generic answer is a trigger.  However, depending on what the "query" does, this might not be possible.  Can you explain what the query does?

Comment: @InputString is ....?

Comment: As has been told you before, keep in mind that you could have the trigger to be triggered just once in case of multiple rows insert

Comment: Again.... @InputString is ....?

Comment: Moreover: has the original question been answered? As you can undestand, changing the question to a different one could make confusion among readers, since the answer is completely meaningless...

Comment: @Simone, Yes partly ,  im trying to  provide an example for future readers.

Comment: For this reason I would have inserted a new question, with a new meaningful title ... for what conern your trigger it doesn't know anything of what is happening outside the table so @inputstring is a useless variable; in the body of the triggers you can use two tables named inserted and deleted in which there are the values that have been inserted and deleted; of course the insert trigger populate only the first one

Comment: @Simone , I will create a new question , to remove any ambiguity for current or future readers that might come across this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use trigger for this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TableInsert]
ON [Table] 
AFTER INSERT
AS
--Do your magic
```

Comment: Nice one. More on triggers here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178110.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could look in to using a Trigger, you can do this on Inserts so every time a new row is inserted it will fire and run your query.